# Accesing element in an array of object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

supposed i have this kind of data from my backend

```
studentInfo = [{
    "id": 20,
    "subject_id": 20,
    "student_id": 3,
    "teacher_id": 2,
    "subjectname": "Algorithm",
    "slug": "algorithm"
}]
```

what if i want to access only on subjectname and slug and render it to my view in html, what is the proper way of doing so without using ng-repeat directive.?

Comment: `studentInfo[index].subjectname` where `index` is an integer, >= 0 and < `studentInfo.length`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>{{ studentInfo[0].slug }}, {{ studentInfo[0].subjectname }} </div>` is this what you're looking for?